# Fast drop-in replacement for "ssh -X"

Tags: ssh, x11, vnc, nx

I'm looking for something to provide faster X11 fowarding than `ssh -X` provides. I do not need a full GUI session or the ability to drop/resume user sessions. I use NX regularly, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to use it without a virtual desktop where all the graphics get painted. (See: http://www.midwinter.com/~koreth/freenx-howto.html) VNC also seems to work only with a virtual desktop; same with X2Go.

What I want is something I can run from a terminal that will only open a graphics window and draw to it when it needs to (like `ssh -X` does). Does this exist? Maybe I've just missed the proper way to do it in something like NX. I've done a ton of searching--I look into this every couple months without a solution--but maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing.

(Full use case: I'm running Sublime Text on a Linux desktop, and I connect to R running on a remote Linux server via SublimeREPL, which is more or less a terminal emulator within Sublime Text. Plotting things from R happens in a forwarded X window, and it's extremely slow using `ssh -XC`. I'd love to be able to send the terminal+graphics connection over NX, but NX doesn't seem to support single applications like this; it forces a full-blown user session with a virtual desktop.)

Comment: Would it make sense to merely render as a .png and then copy the outputted file to your local system and view that in a local image viewer?

Comment: I disagree with closing this as a duplicate.  There are no answers in the other question that actually adress this one.  The answers are: use ssh compression (OP is already doing this) and faster ciphers (unlikely to help in any significant way); using x2go (doesn't integrate into the destop as requested by OP here); using SOCKS rather than SSH (lacks security, will probably not achieve much in the way of performance improvement); a handful of suggestions that are specific to firefox (which OP isn't trying to use).